# How to make Jest test client-side scripts?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I've got some client-side code that I'd like to test with Jest. Let's narrow it down to this reproducible bit:

```
// fetch-example.js
const fetchExample = () => fetch('http://example.org/');
module.exports = fetchExample
```

Since Jest runs tests via Node and Node doesn't support [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), the following test script

```
// fetch-example.test.js
const fetchExample = require('./fetch-example')
test('fetch resolves to something', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return fetchExample().then(() => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

fails with `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`. No surprises, but... `fetchExample` works fine in a browser and I'd like Jest to take this into account and mark the test as passed.

Is there any way to make this work? Is there any parameter I can pass to Jest to include browser functions like `fetch`?

NB: Jest's [browser](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#browser-boolean) configuration entry does not make it work.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: I already know about this package. I could use it but it would require me to reactor large parts of my code. Moreover, I also use classes like [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) that are only available on the client, and who don't always have a node equivalent.

Comment: https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer

Comment: @SLaks nice idea! But this still fails `describe('Client', () => {
    it('should define process', () => expect(!!process).toBe(true));
    it('should define fetch', () => expect(!!fetch).toBe(true));
});` on the second test with the same error (but not on the first one). Any tips?

Comment: How do you possibly expect that to work?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking to run your code in a browser and in Node at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185446/discussion-between-nino-filiu-and-slaks).